# RestTemplate UTF-8 encoding with exchange not working

Tags: java, spring, character-encoding, resttemplate

I am using exchange method of RestTemplate as below but it doesn't encode some characters right.

Original value is : `<Description>Salih'in firewallişççöı ımçööşöşöğ</Description>`
Sent value is:`<Description>Salih'in firewalli?���? ?m���?�?�?</Description>`

Headers are as follows:

```
Content-Type : application/vnd.vmware.admin.edgeGatewayServiceConfiguration+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Accept : application/*+xml;version=5.6
```

This is how i make the request

```
   restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RequestErrorHandler());    
   restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));        
   apiResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, vCloudRequest.getHttpMethod(), entity, responseType);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `RestTemplate` was using `charset=ISO-8859-1` which is given in the `Content-Type` header.
It is checking the `Content-Type` header if any charset is specified and if so it uses that charset.

Comment: You have not shown in the answer how you solved the problem